# Blazor serverside supported browsers

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-11, blazor-server-side

I am looking for a specification, what are supported browser for ASP.NET Core 3.0 Blazor serverside Razor components.

Using this code in my Razor `index.cshtml` shows the news list in Chrome, Firefox, but nothing in IE 11.

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<WEKA.Components.NewsList>(RenderMode.Server))
```

Tried googling but with no success. Not sure if it is just unsupported or it is some bug.

Comment: IE doesn't support webassembly format and can't work with Balzor

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have asked abot Bazor serverside - not webassembly.

Comment: Please, look at this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-3.0) page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supported platforms are here in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Says that you need additional polyfills at the bottom section from polyfill.io for IE 11.

[This](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9436) issue might provide some more insight as well if you run into any issues.

[This](https://github.com/Daddoon/Blazor.Polyfill) github repo has a polyfill for blazor which might help as well.

It also has installation instructions in the readme.

Comment: I see, any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal see my updates for additional links and see if those help out?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had to use the latest fix from here: https://github.com/Daddoon/Blazor.Polyfill/releases/tag/3.0.0